# Run same method in base and derived class

Tags: c#

What do I need to do to first run the method in the base class then run the same method in the derived class? Is this a good idea?

I want run common actions in base class and extend it in the derived class in the same method. Is this how it is usually done?

```
public abstract class MyBase
{
  void DoStuff()
  {
    //some common implementation
  }
}

public class MyDerived : MyBase
{
  void DoStuff()
  {
    // DoStuff in the base first
    // Then DoStuff in here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you talking about something like that?

```
class base
{
  protected virtual void method()
  {
     // do some stuff in base class, something common for all derived classes
  }
}

class derived :  base
{
  public override void method()
  {
    base.method(); // call method from base
    // do here some more work related to this instance of object
  }
}
```

that's not a bad idea, I do use it a lot when I have some common functionality for all derived classes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to  guarantee that the base class logic is run (and not rely on the derived class being polite), you can do this:

```
    public void Method()
    {
        //Stuff that should always happen in base class
        OnMethod();
    }

    protected virtual void OnMethod()
    {
        //Default base class implementation that derived class can either override or extend
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `base.TheMethod()` to run a method in the base class from a derived class.

If you want to run a method of a derived class from a base class, then you have to cast the base class to the derived class. This means that your class needs to be aware of who is deriving it, which breaks encapsulation and should be avoided.